# NGINX check syntax of a certain file only

Tags: nginx

I'm writing a GUI where users can edit their NGINX vhost information. Before updating their vhost I would like to perform a syntax check. That's why my idea was to copy the new contents to `tmp` first and then run a NGINX syntax check only on that certain file (instead of `nginx -t` which will check all vhosts and only in the appropriate nginx-directories).

Is is somehow possible to syntax-check one certain file only before pasting it from `/tmp/new_vhost_content` to `/etc/nginx/sites-enables/vhost`?

Comment: I hope you have proper validation for the configuration, like checking if user uses a `root` path he is supposed to use etc. If you allow free editing of nginx configuration, that is way too open approach waiting for abuse to happen.

Comment: Thanks I'm considering that. What else would you check except the `root` path?

Comment: Anything that might expose other users' data, like FastCGI sockets etc. However, I cannot provide any exhaustive list since I am not implementing it myself and it is a big effort to properly evaluate the risks.. You need to think through it yourself and decide if you are happy with your solution. I wouldn't implement free editing myself at all due to risks involved.

Answer (score 8):

To check a single config use the parameter **-c** ex. `nginx -t -c /path/to/conf`

Comment: +1 Thank you. Is there a possibity to wrap `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` around it, because it' expects that, otherwise, if I have only a file with a `server{}` directive it will throw an error because of the missing wrapper.

Comment: @chevallier that doesn't really make any sense. A computer can't validate only a tiny portion of the configuration out of context.